# Understanding the function $f(z) = \left(\frac{z}{z + x_0} \right)^{\kappa}$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, multivalued-functions

I have the following complex function:
$$f(z) = \left(\frac{z}{z + x_0} \right)^{\kappa}$$

where $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ and $x_0 > 0$. $\kappa$ is a parameter for which we look at three cases:

1. case: $\kappa \in \mathbb N$ and $\kappa \neq 1$
2. case: $\kappa \in \mathbb Q$
3. case: $\kappa \in \mathbb I$, i.e. $\kappa$ is irrational

My professor told me that for the first two cases, we get a finite number of Riemann sheets for $f(z)$. But in the 3. case we get an infinite number of Riemann sheets.

My understanding/assumptions regarding the first two cases:
First, by Riemann sheets I mean branches of a multivalued function.

If $\kappa$ is rational (which also includes the $\kappa \in \mathbb N$ case), it has the form $\kappa = \frac{m}{n}$ with $n \neq 0$. Therefore, we can rewrite $f(z)$ as $f(z) = \frac{z^{\frac{m}{n}}}{(z + x_0)^{\frac{m}{n}}} = \frac{(z^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{((z + x_0)^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$. As far as I understand it, for both $(z^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $((z + x_0)^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, the $\frac{1}{n}$ "part" is what causes the branches, since this represents the $n$-th root and we know that any function $g(z) = z^{\frac{1}{n}}$ has exactly $n$ branches. Therefore, the number of branches is finite.

But why is it that when $\kappa$ is irrational, the number of branches becomes infinite?

And this function somehow "more known" in mathematics and/or physics and thus more studied? Does it have a name?

I somehow understood my professor that it appears in the definition of a propagator in Quantum Field Theory, but I'm not entirely sure.

And if I made a mistake somewhere in my understanding, please feel free to correct me.

P.S. is there a more formal proof (or explanation) which shows why for rational $\kappa$ the number of Riemann sheets is finite but for irrational it's infinite?

Comment: Are you happy with the corresponding claims about $g(w) = w^{\kappa}$? <> Laws of exponents with complex expressions need more care than they do over the real numbers, but that just means I'd be skeptical of the remarks when $\kappa$ is rational, even if the conclusion is correct. The main issue is the behavior of exponentiation with irrational exponent.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I'm not sure that I can say that I'm happy about the claims, but rather that it is how I, at least tried, to interpret it. But like I said, if there is something wrong in my interpretation and if there is a more rigorous description as to why it would hold for rational powers that there are finitely many Riemann sheets, I'd be happy to be referred to some literature that has this covered, including the irrational powers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Log}{Log}\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}\DeclareMathOperator{\pow}{\texttt{powC}}$Let $\kappa$ be a real number, let $\Log$ denote the principal branch of logarithm (satisfying $-\pi < \im\Log \leq \pi$), and let $\log$ denote the "total logarithm", which assigns to a non-zero complex number $w$ the set of *all* complex numbers $u$ satisfying $w = \exp u$. In other words, if $w \neq 0$, then
\begin{align*}
  \log w &= \{\Log w + 2\pi ni : \text{$n$ an integer}\} \\
  &= (\Log w) + 2\pi i \mathbf{Z}.
\end{align*}

Define the "total $\kappa$th power function," formally $z^{\kappa}$ but less freighted with expectations about rules of exponents, by
\begin{align*}
  \pow(w, \kappa) &= \exp(\kappa\log w) \\
  &= \{\exp(\kappa\Log w + 2\pi n\kappa i) : \text{$n$ an integer}\} \\
  &= \{\exp(\kappa\Log w) \cdot \exp(2\pi n\kappa i) : \text{$n$ an integer}\}.
\end{align*}
The factor $\exp(\kappa\Log w)$ is well-defined because $\Log$ is single-valued (despite the discontinuity on the non-positive real axis). The multi-valuedness, if any, therefore arises from the set $\{\exp(2\pi n\kappa i) : \text{$n$ an integer}\}$.

Because $\exp(2\pi n\kappa i) = 1$ if and only if $n\kappa$ is an integer, we deduce:

- If $\kappa$ is an integer, then $\exp(2\pi n\kappa i) = 1$ for every integer $n$, and $\pow(\ , \kappa)$ is single-valued.
- If $\kappa = p/q$ is rational in lowest terms and $1 < q$, then
  $$
  \exp(2\pi n\kappa i) = \exp(2\pi npi/q)
  $$
  takes precisely $q$ distinct values as $n$ runs over the integers, so $\pow(\ , \kappa)$ is $q$-valued.
- If $\kappa$ is irrational, then $\exp(2\pi n\kappa i) = 1$ if and only if $n\kappa$ is an integer, if and only if $n = 0$. Consequently, if $n$ and $n'$ are integers, then $\exp(2\pi n\kappa i) = \exp(2\pi n'\kappa i)$ if and only if
  $$
  1 = \frac{\exp(2\pi n\kappa i)}{\exp(2\pi n'\kappa i)}
  = \exp\bigl(2\pi (n - n')\kappa i\bigr),
  $$
  if and only if $n = n'$. We conclude $\pow(\ , \kappa)$ takes infinitely many distinct values, one for each integer $n$.

<>

So what about the function $f$ in question? The conceptual point is, $w := z/(z + x_{0})$ is an injective function of $z$ (given by a Möbius transformation), so the multi-valuedness of $f$ mirrors multi-valuedness of $\pow(\ , \kappa)$ with two exceptions:

- If $z = 0$ then $w = 0$ and $f$ is undefined.
- If $z = -x_{0}$, then $w = \infty$ (or is undefined, depending if we're working in the Riemann sphere or the complex plane), and again $f$ is undefined.

Comment: Thank You very much Andrew! Is it in general true that, if an injective function given by a Möbius transformation mirrors the multi-valuedness of $\pow (\ , \kappa)$?

Comment: Briefly _yes_: Qualitatively, if we compose a multi-valued function with an injection we get a multi-valued function with the same behavior. <> Here, each value of $z$ other than $0$ and $-z_0$ gives a unique non-zero $w$, which gives the stated number of values of $f(z) = \texttt{powC}\,(w, \kappa)$.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand it correctly: Let $v = f(z)$ be an injective function of $z$. If this is the case, then $v^{\kappa}$ will mirror the behaviour of $\pow(w, \kappa)$ as described in your answer? The key part being that $v =f(z)$ MUST BE injective?

Comment: I was being a bit lazy. In more detail, if $f$ is an arbitrary function, then $v = f(z)$ is a single complex number, so $v^\kappa = f(z)^\kappa$ has the multi-valued behavior described whether or not $f$ is injective. <> Injectivity _may_ matter if we "post-compose," i.e., consider $f(z^{\kappa})$. If $f$ is injective, then $g(z) = f(z^\kappa)$ has the multi-valued behavior described. If $f$ is not injective, the question of injectivity of $g$ comes down to whether or not $f$ identifies any values of $z^{\kappa}$.

Comment: So any arbitrary $v = f(z)$ will, when taking $v^{\kappa} = (f(z))^{\kappa}$, have the same behavior as $\pow(w, \kappa) = \exp(\kappa \log(w))$ ? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, e.g., if $\kappa = p/q$ in lowest terms, then $f(z)^\kappa$ takes $q$ values at each $z$ with $f(z) \neq 0$, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks! What I still don't understand is why at $z= 0$ the function is undefined and not simply $f(z=0) = 0$ ?

Comment: The restriction $f(z) \neq 0$ in my prior comment was because we're discussing multi-valuedness. :) <> We can define $0^\kappa = 0$ for positive $\kappa$, obtaining a continuous extension, but if $\kappa$ isn't a positive integer then (i) $0$ is a boundary point of the domain, and (ii) the power function isn't even formally differentiable if $\kappa < 1$ (the difference quotients at $0$ are unbounded).