# Laurent series of $f(z) = \left(\frac{z}{z + x_0}\right)^{\kappa}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I want to determine the Laurent series of the function
$$f(z) = \left(\frac{z}{z + x_0}\right)^{\kappa}$$, where $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ and $x_0 > 0$,$\kappa$ is either an integer, a rational number or an irrational number,  expanded at $z_0=0$.
With some "intuition", I think $z_0 = 0$ is a good point for expansion precisely because at that point $f(z)$ is not defined.

I know that the Laurent series is given by $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$ which can be split up into the analytic part $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$ and the principal part $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{-n} (z-z_0)^{-n}$.

Because we have a pole at $z= -x_0$, we look at two cases:

1. $|z| < x_0$
2. $|z| > x_0$

What I managed to do is to determine the Laurent series for $f(z) = \frac{z}{z+x_0}$ and I got $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{z^{n+1}}{x_0^{n+1}}$ for the first case and $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x_0^n}{z^n}$ for the second case. From my understanding, $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{z^{n+1}}{x_0^{n+1}}$ is the analytic part and $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x_0^n}{z^n}$ is the principal part.

Can this result be somehow used for $f(z) = \left(\frac{z}{z + x_0}\right)^{\kappa}$ ?

Another idea was to rewrite the function as $f(z) = e^{\kappa \log(\frac{z}{z+x_0})}$ but I'm not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Generally (as discussed at your [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769043/understanding-the-function-fz-left-fraczz-x-0-right-kappa) :) $f$ isn't single-valued in any neighborhood of $0$, so $0$ is not an isolated singularity and there is no Laurent expansion about $0$. It's the same issue with trying to expand "the complex square root" at $0$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang i just saw your reply at the other question. thanks for the clarification!
Where should I do the expansion then? Can I do it at the pole $x_0$ ?

Comment: The zero and pole are precisely the places where (in general) no Laurent expansion exists, because $f$ is not (generally) single-valued in any neighborhood. A Laurent expansion can handle isolated singularities, but it's still single-valued where defined. <> As a general note, complex analysis courses make a big deal of _isolated singularities_, but often don't emphasize that series alone cannot be used to represent branching behavior, even though branching occurs at isolated points. At a branch point, we have to remove a _cut_ to get something holomorphic; that's not an isolated singularity.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I think I (somehow) get it now. So because of the multi-valuedness of $f(z)$, there is no "single" Laurent series for the whole function, but one can rather define it for a specific branch? And if so, how about the expansion around $z = \frac{x_0}{2}$ ? The points $z=0$ and $z = x_0$ would then lie exactly on the circle around the expansion point and thus not be included

Comment: Expanding a particular branch about the midpoint is possible. Offhand I'd proceed as in the proof of Newton's binomial theorem, calculating derivatives and using the Taylor series formula. (Any two branches will be equal up to a multiplied constant $1^{\kappa} = \exp(2\pi m\kappa i)$ for some integer $m$.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Isn't Newton's binomial theorem too restrictive? As defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem under "Newton's generalized binomial theorem", we have $\frac{1}{(1+x)^s} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-s}{n}x^n$ with the restriction $|x| < 1$ and $-s$ cannot be a non-negative integer. I can rewrite $\frac{z}{z+x_0}$ into $\frac{1}{1+\frac{x_0}{z}}$ so I have a similar form to $\frac{1}{1+x}$, but (i) $\frac{z}{z+x_0}$ is raised to $\kappa$, which means I have $(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x_0}{z}})^{\kappa}$ and I'm not sure if I can just "ignore" $1^{\kappa}$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang and (ii) in my case we can have $ |\frac{x_0}{z}| > 1$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang and (iii) $\kappa$ can be any negative real number, whereas $s$ is not allowed to be a negative integer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148901/discussion-between-andrew-d-hwang-and-syphracos).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I wrote you 2 in the chat, did you get the message?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  did you get my last messages?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang could You maybe look one more time in the messages? Thank You!